# webpack-dev-server start but doesn't reload on file changes

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, reload

I can't figure out why webpack is not reloading the page when a modification is detected. DevServer starts successful but doesn't automatically reload a page when code changes in the editor (js and css). I have to manually refresh the browser to see the changes.

I lost a couple of days and tried a lot of different settings but nothing works.
Now I am in the middle of a project, I can't drop webpack and the manual reloading starts to take a few seconds due to the size of the project itself. Only can save me now DevServer automatically reload.
Can anyone help me?

My project structure:
[image: file Structure]

Here is my webpack.dev.js config:

```
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const WebpackBar = require("webpackbar");

module.exports = {

mode: "development",
entry: {
       index: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
},

output: {                                    
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),  
    filename: "js/[name].js",                
},

devServer: {                           
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    watchContentBase: true,
    compress: true,                    
    port: 9001,              
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
        poll: true,
        ignored: "/node_modules/"
    }
},

stats: {                              
    modules: false,
    entrypoints: false,
},

plugins: [
    new WebpackBar({}),                       
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({}),   
    new CopyPlugin({                           
        patterns: [
            { from: "src/static/img", to: "static/img" },          
            { from: "src/static/models", to: "static/models" },     
        ],
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({                        
        filename: "css/[name].css",                    
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",     
        filename: 'index.html',           
        inject: "body",                   
        chunks: ['index'],
    })
],

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
            use: [
                { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, options: {} },
                { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } },
                { loader: "postcss-loader", options: {} },
                { loader: "sass-loader", options: {} },
            ]
        },
    ],
},
}
```

Here is my script :

```
"live": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js",
```

message I get after run script:

```
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9001/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\isladjan\Desktop\RaD\dist
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
...
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Versions I'm running:

```
node: v15.13.0
"webpack": "^5.24.4",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
```

Readings from: http://localhost:9001/webpack-dev-server
[files which webpack-dev-server served](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bx2J.jpg)

Comment: Are you expecting [hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/)?

Comment: I tried HMR but it doesn't work either. Maybe if I found and correct the error in the current settings for  automatically reload - maybe HRP will work too.